# Record syntax field type annotation having only smart constructor

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a record where one of the fields has a type that is not exported, since it's using a smart constructor. Using the smart constructor as the type does not work.

```
 Not in scope: type variable `domain'
```

Maybe there is a language extension that allows me to do this, or something similar?

Exporting the constructor along with the smart constructor would allow me to solve this problem, but that in turn creates the possibility of creating values that the smart constructor wouldn't allow.

The (non-working) code I have right now:

```
import Domain (domain) -- Domain is not exported, and domain is a smart constructor for Domain

data Rec = Rec
    { dint :: domain Int -- what do I do here? I want it to be `Domain Int` but `Domain` isn't exported.
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Please include your code. It's very difficult to tell what is going on here.

Comment: It sounds like you are probably getting types and type constructors mixed up. However, I can't tell from what you have posted.

Comment: @Kwarrtz added code.

Comment: If you could add the definitions of your `Domain` type and `domain` smart constructor, that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is confusion between the concept of a **type constructor** and a **data constructor**. For brevity, I will illustrate the difference with an example.

```
data Foo a = Bar [a]
```

In the expression above, `Foo` is the type constructor and `Bar` is the data constructor. The key difference is that `Foo` is a value in Haskell's type space and `Bar` is a value in its data space. A value in type space cannot be used in data space, and vice versa. For example, the compiler would error at the following expressions.

```
someVariable :: Bar Int
someVariable = Foo [15]
```

The next expression, however, is completely valid.

```
someVariable :: Foo Int
someVariable = Bar [15]
```

Additionally, all type constructors **must start with an upper case letter**. Any types starting with a lower case letter will be considered type variables, not type constructors (the `a` in our definition above is an example of this).

The introduction of smart constructors add another layer to this problem, but the key thing to understand is that **smart constructors are data constructors, not type constructors**. In your definition of `Rec`, you tried to use your smart constructor, `domain`, in the type declaration for `dint` field. However, because `domain` is a data constructor not a type constructor, and it is lower case, the Haskell compiler tried to interpret `domain` as the name of a type variable. Because you never specified a variable named `domain` in your definiton of the `Rec` type, the compiler raised an error.

You don't actually need to export the data constructor for `Domain` to solve the issue, just the type itself. This can be accomplished with the following.

```
module Domain (
    Domain(), domain,
    ...
    ) where
```

Including `Domain()` in the export definition tells Haskell to export the `Domain` type constructor, but not any of its data constructors. This preserves the safety you wanted with the safe constructor, and allows you to define types correctly. You can now use your newly exported type in your definition of `Rec`.

```
import Domain (Domain(), domain)

data Rec = Rec
    { dint :: Domain Int
    ...
    }
```

For more information, I strongly recommend you read the HaskellWiki articles on [constructors](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constructor) and [smart constructors](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors).

Comment: If I understood correctly, and I certainly might not have given the question, I think the type itself is not exported.  If that's the case he certainly has a problem and should export the type or file an issue with the library author.  It wouldn't be the first time.